# Is there a way to reuse a part of code to instantiate array-lists that hold different data types?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, arraylist, subclass

I wanted to find a way of reusing similar array lists in my code in Java. The only thing that makes each one different is the data type they hold. Particularly in my program I have a class `ActionDeck` that has an instance variable array list of object `ActionCard` and another class `SalaryDeck` that has an instance variable array list of object `SalaryCard`. Both of these classes have the same instance variables and methods. Is there a way I am able to have some kind of blueprint wherein I can just instantiate both **Deck** classes from one part of code but the object it holds is different? The abstract `Deck` class it extends from holds similar methods only. I just want to shorten the amount of code since I'm repeating these for other deck classes and it seems redundant too.

```
public class SalaryDeck extends Deck {
    
    private Deque<SalaryCard> salaryDeck;
    private ArrayList<SalaryCard> temp;

    public SalaryDeck () {
        salaryDeck = new ArrayDeque<SalaryCard>();
        temp = new ArrayList<SalaryCard>();
    }
```

```
public class ActionDeck extends Deck {

    // Instance variables for an action card deck
    private Deque<ActionCard> actionDeck;
    private ArrayList<ActionCard> temp;

    /**
     * Constructor for an action card deck object. It creates a temporary
     * array list, as well as a deque for pushing action card objects into.
     */
    public ActionDeck() {
        actionDeck = new ArrayDeque<ActionCard>();
        temp = new ArrayList<ActionCard>();
    }
```

I kept thinking I could use an abstract class but I'm not sure of how to implement it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You make your `Deck` class generic:

```java
public abstract class Deck<C> {
   protected final Deque<C> cards = new Deque<>();
}

public class ActionDeck extends Deck<ActionCard> {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped eliminate repeating lines of codes on multiple classes of my program, cheers!